# Невозможно запустить windows  из-за апаратных ошибок.

Tags: windows

Скачал в инете програму, начал устанавливать, в итоге на весь экран высветился бан. Виндовс заблокирован, отправьте смс на номер, ну, я попробовал запустить диспечер задач -ничего не получилось. Тогда начал переустанавливать виндовс, запустил с CD акронис отформатировал все диски, затем начал установку, все шло хорошо. Потом, когда комп перезагрузился, поставил загрузку с  жесткого, и мне высветило: "Невозможно запустить windows  из за апаратных ошибок". До этого случая ставил виндовс никаких проблем не было. Уже раза три пробовал - результат ноль. У меня  HDD sata. Потом я поставил на HDD сата конвертер вот такой

http://www.usb.ua/ru/image/large/perehodnik_stlab_s-250_art90405.jpg

подключил его к IDE. Все за работало. Но когда ставишь все как надо, через сата кабель высвечивает: "Невозможно запустить windows из-за апаратных ошибок". Может кто-то знает, как исправить эту проблему? Заранее всем благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Зайти в БИОС и изменить режим работы SATA Mode = AHCI на SATA Mode = Compatible IDE. Названия опций могут немного отличаться.
Заодно проконтролировать опцию ACPI OS Installed = YES/NO